# Php Code doesn't echo to screen

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a login system. When the user clicks submit it should output to the screen if the entered credentials "Exist" or "Doesn't Exist", but nothing appears on the screen. Why is that? Also I have a database i created with phpmyadmin that is called "users" inside my sample database.

```
<?php  

//Database connection

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "root");
define("DATABASE", "sample");



?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.2.0", ">")){

    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        if($mysqli->connecterrno){
            echo "Please fix database connection.";
            exit;
            }
        $prepare_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $prepare_stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $password = hash("sha256", $_POST['password']);
        $prepare_stmt->execute();
        $prepare_stmt->store_result();

        echo $password . "<br />";

        if($prepare_stmt->num_rows){
            echo "Exists";
            } else {

                echo "Doesn't Exist";

                }
    } else {

        ?><form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="user"><br />
       <input type="password" name="password"><br />
       <button type="submit">Login</button>

        </form><?php
    }
    }else{


        ?>Please update your PHP Version to suit these code settings.       
    <?php


    }
?>
```

Error

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$connecterrno in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php on line 13

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php on line 14

Comment: I fixed the issues you stated and now when I click submit I get the error I posted above. I don't know what ^^^^ is and where would I put isset() I'm following a tutorial and they didn't put that anywhere?

Comment: Define your username/password variables before you do your query.  @Fred -ii- Thanks from before. ;)

Comment: You need to use `isset()` for one thing.

Comment: I fixed the errors, but when I click submit now I get the error posted above. Also I don't know where I'd put isset(); I'm following a tutorial and they don't use one?

Comment: I personally would do this completely diff, but at the bottom you have your submit button, so at the top you can use `if(ISSET($_POST['submit']))` and it'll check if you submitted or not, if you did then it'll execute the code.

Comment: do you need password `root`? try leaving the password field blank.

Comment: might I suggest that before you go too far with this design idea that you think about storing passwords in an encrypted for in the db? Not hashed, encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have error in line `if($mysqli->connecterrno){` you should use `connect_errno`. Secondly, you have access denied error wich means your database connection credentials are wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that bit didn't look right to me earlier. Good catch on that.

Comment: I agree. and im sure theres no password needed for default mysql settings

Comment: Going off what CodeGodie just said, it's good practice to protect/password your root account. ;)

Comment: I just setup my work environment using xampp. How do I setup the credentials for mysql?

Comment: Try as mentioned above leaving password line blank.

Comment: You should also remove `password` from you mysqli-connection creation statement